# Can I swap between two RAIDs on one NAS?

Tags: raid, nas, synology

Weird question, confuses Google, not sure where to ask. I want to buy a Synology DS923+ NAS enclosure and load it up with 4 RAIDed drives. Then I'd like to remove those 4 drives and put them away, just to keep as an emergency backup. THEN I'd like to put 4 new drives into the NAS and create a new RAID, which I will use on a daily basis. Finally, should an emergency ever occur, I'd like to be able to swap between the two different RAIDs as needed, using the same enclosure. Can I do this?

I have no idea how one of these gets set up/configured in the first place, so if the answer to my question is super obvious to anyone who does, please forgive. Thanks!

JMT

The enclosure in question:
https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1735213-REG/synology_ds923_4_bay_nas_enclosure.html

Comment: I cannot answer your question.  However, good drives will last a very long time and not likely need an emergency backup. Drives put away and not run for a very long time may not start properly. Might be worth your while to think this one through.

Comment: That's a good point. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 0):

It would work. The NAS software would be old, but so will the files.

Raid protects you from drives going bad. The only reason for doing anything more, like me, is to protect against fire, floods or burglary.

So I have a smaller NAS box at a friends place  to which I sync to.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So the Synology software that runs the NAS is installed on the hard drives? I would have thought it was on-board firmware somewhere. I watched a few videos on setup but nothing I found mentions that.